# How to enable Apache Wicket debugging

Tags: java, debugging, wicket

I have started using Wicket v9.15.0 for a couple of projects.  I have come across the following error on building code several times:

> ERROR org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupFactory - Markup not found: Base
> markup of inherited markup not found. Component class: xxx.xxx.xxx.
> Enable debug messages for
> org.apache.wicket.core.util.resource.locator.ResourceStreamLocator to
> get a list of all filenames tried.

I have spent hours reading the (mostly unhelpful) documentation and examples and, of course, time searching the web but cannot find how this is done.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Googling for "wicket logging" for a second should have given you this (imho actually very helpful) link: https://wicket.apache.org/start/wicket-9.x.html#logging
It says "You cannot use Wicket without adding an SLF4J logging implementation to your classpath."
So please consult the manual of your chosen logger on how to set the log level for the specified class

Comment: slf4j already added. But setting debug for log4j was not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create a simplelogger.properties file in eg, src/main/resources with org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel = debug.